# ActiveCollab API - requesting Daily Capacity

Tags: api, activecollab

ActiveCollab has some very strong features in the UI related to resource management - capacity, scheduling, workload, calendars etc.

I would like to access these data set via the API, but nothing seems to be available per the documentation here: https://developers.activecollab.com/api-documentation/index.html (except Days-off)

Specifically, I'm looking to request daily capacity for all users.

No googling or dialogue with their support have been able to point me to an answer.